# Rest position of pin binding over summer?

Tags: gear, skiing, cross-country-skiing, ski-bindings

I have an ATK Crest 10 binding. What should be the position of the pin binding over summer when the binding is not used for a long time (a few months)?

Should the binding be fully opened or in the skiing position?

Which position is better for the springs in the binding?

Comment: Whichever position has the spring with as little tension as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user manual (page 41) says that

> When not used, set the binding as per the downhill mode in order to preserve the elasticity of the springs

The manual is downloadable [on the manufacturer site](https://www.atkbindings.com/fr/downloads-fr/)